# The close() cancle() function of Flink RichParallelSourceFunction does not work

Tags: parallel-processing, flink-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc, application-shutdown, flink-batch

The Flink Job is running in the workflow on the GCP DataProc cluster.
A timeout is set for the workflow task, and the **Dag is forcibly terminated after the set time**.

At this time, **the close and cancel functions of Flink RichParallelSourceFunction do not work**.

```
public class SampleSource extends RichParallelSourceFunction<Data> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleSource.class);
    private volatile boolean running;
    SourceFunction sf;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        running = true;
        sf = new SourceFunction();
        sf.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Data> ctx) throws Exception {
        while (running) {
            List<Data> data = sf.getData();
            data.forEach(ctx::collect);
            Thread.sleep(1000*10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            logger.info("[Job Cancelled]");
            sf.updateTimestamp();
            this.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.info("[Job Closed]");
            running = false;
            sf.close();
            super.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            sf.updateTimestamp();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I checked the log, the close and cancel functions don't seem to work.
Only TaskExecutorStateChangelogStoragesManager work.

```
2023-06-08 08:03:21,169 INFO state.TaskExecutorStateChangelogStoragesManager: Shutting down TaskExecutorStateChangelogStoragesManager.
2023-06-08 08:03:21,170 INFO state.TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager: Shutting down TaskExecutorLocalStateStoresManager.
2023-06-08 08:03:21,169 INFO blob.PermanentBlobCache: Shutting down BLOB cache
2023-06-08 08:03:21,170 INFO blob.TransientBlobCache: Shutting down BLOB cache
2023-06-08 08:03:21,170 INFO filecache.FileCache: removed file cache directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-...
2023-06-08 08:03:21,173 INFO disk.FileChannelManagerImpl: FileChannelManager removed spill file directory /tmp/flink-netty-shuffle-...
```

I want to trigger the last **sf.close()**. How can I do it?